# Different storyboard for different screen

Tags: ios, storyboard

Apple approve this solution? I call in appDelegate different storyboard for different resolutions. I wild not use autolayout. 
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-uistoryboards-depending-on-screen-height-in-ios/

```
- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {

// determine screen size
int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
UIStoryboard *storyboard;

switch (screenHeight) {

        // iPhone 4s
    case 480:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-4s" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 5s
        case 568:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-5s" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6
        case 667:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6" bundle:nil];
        break;

        // iPhone 6 Plus
        case 736:
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6-Plus" bundle:nil];
        break;

    default:
        // it's an iPad
        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        break;
}

return storyboard;
```

}

Comment: You can do that, sure, but you are making more work for yourself. Also in your "iPad" storyboard you need to deal with the different sizes for the iPad Pro and split screen modes, so you will need to use autolayout anyway.  What do you do if the iPhone 7 has a different resolution when it is announced tomorrow?

Comment: ok , thank you for answer. I mean ... if something were to be different , for example , from iphone 5 to iphone 6 , apple would approve ? maybe some bigger size of iPhone 5 compared to 6. You Understand ? @Paulw11

Comment: As long as your app works correctly it should be fine, but autolayout and size classes are there to eliminate the need to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you very much!

Comment: why don't you want to use auto layout?

Comment: @VandilsonLima in reality it seems quite complicated and I do not have much time to do it . so I only need to resize something. and even if it seems better to a bigger size of a device compared to another I can do it

Comment: usually when auto layout is to hard to do the problem is the app design. At least for me.

Comment: Here's a lecture from Stanford University's CS193P covering AutoLayout in iOS9. Learning the basics would save you a ton of time. Lecture notes & slides are available on iTunesU. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBzzfaTj4vg

Comment: Auto layout for me seems a lot easier than using code, only complicated if you want advanced layout